# PrototypeCells Not Appearing

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am trying to write an app with a 'main page' of `UIButtons` that when tapped will Segue to `UITableView`, which will in turn Segue to another View etc. I have no errors or warnings in my code, and I thought I designed it well, but when I run the app the PrototypeCells don't even appear.

[This is how I have my Storyboard set up right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b50m.png) (I'm sorry but I can't post images yet, as I'm a new user). The little beer mug is a UIButton that successfully performs the Segue to the UITableView window (this is the one that doesn't load the PrototypeCells).

The Brew View Controller has no code in it other than the defaulted methods.

I created a class called Brewery and gave it the following properties

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *info;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *brews;
```

I created the Brewery View Controller and added the following methods along with the default code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.breweries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BreweryCell"];
    Brewery *brewObject = [self.breweries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //might be an error in here
    cell.textLabel.text = brewObject.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Yet when I run this, the PrototypeCells aren't even showing. The ReuseIdentifier matches both in storyboard and in the code, and the View is attached to the dataSource and the Delegate. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I am also new to site, so please tell me if there is something I am doing wrong or if you need more information to assist me.

Comment: Do you see anything inthe screen after the segue at all?

Comment: Yes, after the segue I see the Navigation Bar at the top saying 'Find a Brewery', but thats it, so I know the segue IS working. Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: Add a log statement to `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` that shows the what `[self breweries]` evaluates to: is it nil? How many items are there?

Comment: Is this the correct log statement to see that? I have

    `return [self.breweries count];
    NSLog(@"%@",self);`

but nothing is printing to my log

Comment: Even when I make the log statement `NSLog(@"this is a test");` nothing shows up in the log when inserted into the `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. It DOES however show up in the log if I place it in the AppDelegate.m file...strange. It seems as if that method/file is never being used..?

Comment: Upon further testing it seems that the `(void)viewDidLoad` method is working in the BreweryViewController, but none of the other methods seem to be accessed when I segue to that View...this leads me to believe it has to be something with either the prototype cells that I set up, or perhaps I need to add/alter something in my StoryBoard? I truly am stumped at this point...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have said you have set the dataSource, if `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is not being called then it means the data source is not set correctly.

I suggest checking this in `viewDidAppear` and logging the data source and delegate, and programatically checking the equal self.

There are a few pitfalls with setting IBOutlets in interface builder.

From what you have said in your blurb:

> the View is attached to the dataSource and the Delegate

This is wrong.  It should be the file's owner which is the View Controller.